# The fastest data transfer iPhone->Apple watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I am using the Apple Watch to trigger haptic feedback from an iPhone application and the update rate is of essence. I have tried out the following methods:

```
[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:...];
[[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:..];
```

to send data from the iPhone app to the Apple Watch but I experiene a lag when the small data is sent in a short time frame. I send the data every 0.1 second now and the Apple watch seems to stack up the messages. Any idea on what method that is the best for fast data transfer? And what are the limitations?

Answer (score 0):

The data are sent from Watch to companion app (or vice-versa) using timing defined by the Operating System and is not possible to control it. The data are transferred as soon as possible. This is a "way" to avoid the development of some applications that can consume the battery in the watch and in the iPhone. 
Another reason is the Watch or iPhone can't spent all the resource (processor, memory, time) only for your app but need time for other tasks.

You can try to send the messages as fast possible but iOS will assigns the most proper time to the queue. I hope this can help you